# How to use Google Finance to fetch stock data when the column contains stock ticker?

Tags: google-sheets-formula, google-finance

The B3 cell contains the stock ticker symbol say TCS.
When i try to execute

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("NSE:B3","PRICE")
```

The formula is giving error "When evaluating GOOGLEFINANCE, the query for the symbol: 'B3' returned no data."
I want TCS to be used instead of B3. Can you suggest

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("NSE:"&B3,"PRICE")
```